# Its taking too much time to enter value in field using sendkeys() in Appium (Android)

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium, sendkeys

I am trying to enter value in an input field and it's taking 3-4 minutes in entering the value using sendKeys.
I've already tried using / removing raw, implicit and explicit waits for element. I've also tried changing my locator strategy. I have printed the xml before entering the value and the element is present in XML. I am unable to identify the issue here.

##### Code

```
locator.clear();
locator.click();
locator.sendKeys(value);
```

##### APPIUM LOGS

> POST /wd/hub/session/9a33c354-03a4-4772-97cb-9aaedd40bfce/element/68b0462a-bbe4-4a3f-8eed-1a7de8d6f659/value
> [HTTP] {"id":"68b0462a-bbe4-4a3f-8eed-1a7de8d6f659","text":"067384633","value":["0","6","7","3","8","4","6","3","3"]}
> [W3C (9a33c354)] Calling AppiumDriver.setValue() with args: [["0","6","7","3","8","4","6","3","3"],"68b0462a-bbe4-4a3f-8eed-1a7de8d6f659","9a33c354-03a4-4772-97cb-9aaedd40bfce"]
> [WD Proxy] Matched '/element/68b0462a-bbe4-4a3f-8eed-1a7de8d6f659/value' to command name 'setValue'
> [Protocol Converter] Added 'value' property ["0","6","7","3","8","4","6","3","3"] to 'setValue' request body
> [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element/68b0462a-bbe4-4a3f-8eed-1a7de8d6f659/value] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8201/wd/hub/session/39a3b84a-6b5c-4075-a32b-7349af88196b/element/68b0462a-bbe4-4a3f-8eed-1a7de8d6f659/value] with body: {"elementId":"68b0462a-bbe4-4a3f-8eed-1a7de8d6f659","text":"067384633","replace":false,"value":["0","6","7","3","8","4","6","3","3"]}

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Actions` class.

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.sendKeys("xyz");
a.perform();
```